# Using graphviz module in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I need use the graphviz module. this is first time.

I performed following steps.

1. Open the OSGEO4W shell and run **py3_env** commend and installed graphviz module by using
   **python -m pip install graphviz**
2. Set the system environment variables added the **graphviz/bin,graphviz/bin/dot.exe** paths to system environment path variable
   [image]
   [image]

then I tried small code

```
import graphviz

print('Graphviz running')
dot = graphviz.Digraph('YPN-PN-101', comment='SLD')
dot.node('YPN-CA-1', 'CABINATE')
dot.node('YPN-AN-1-1', 'AN1')
dot.node('YPN-AN-2-1', 'AN2')
dot.node('YPN-AN-3-1', 'AN3')
dot.node('YPN-AN-4-1', 'AN4')
dot.node('YPN-PN-102', 'PN')
dot.node('YPN-IJ-102', 'IJ')

dot.edge('YPN-CA-1', 'YPN-AN-1-1', label='YPN-SN-1-1')
dot.edge('YPN-AN-1-1', 'YPN-AN-2-1', label='YPN-SN-1-2')
dot.edge('YPN-AN-2-1', 'YPN-AN-3-1', label='YPN-SN-1-3')
dot.edge('YPN-AN-3-1', 'YPN-AN-4-1', label='YPN-SN-1-4')
dot.edge('YPN-AN-4-1', 'YPN-PN-102', label='Fiber')
dot.edge('YPN-PN-102', 'YPN-IJ-102', label='Fiber')
dot.render(directory=r'D:\SLD-diagram\doctest-output', view=True)
```

graphviz module imported sucessfully. but its throws the following error

```
failed to execute 'dot', make sure the graphviz executables are on your systems' path
```

but paths are added to system variable

How to resolve this?

Comment: It's not a GIS or QGIS module, it's a Python module to create graphs, so I vote to close this one. Please ask on StackOverflow general informatic questions.

Comment: Graphs in this meaning are networks, and visualisation of networks is a GIS task so should not be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @user2856 above code tried on QGIS python Console. restarted the application but still no working

Comment: i added the full path. please check images in Question

Comment: @user2856: I mean here it's not a graph problem, no projection, no coordinates, just a Python module that doesn't work, so for me it's general informatic problem, not GIS.

Comment: @J.Monticolo yes agreed in this specific instance, but the software is useful for GIS related visualisation and the question may have value for others so I voted to keep it. Questions about installing other GIS related libraries are on-topic. But I'm just one vote and if the community votes to close it, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

first uninstall all related graphviz then proceed following

1. go to [graphviz site](https://graphviz.org/download/) and download the graphviz exe
2. install the graphviz exe and while installing select the add path
3. installation done.go to Environmental variables and add the gaphviz path

[image]

4. goto osgeo4w shell and install the graphviz module with `python -m pip intsall graphviz` commend
5. add below two lines before your code

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

final code

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
import graphviz

print('Graphviz running')
dot = graphviz.Digraph('YPN-PN-101', comment='SLD')
dot.node('YPN-CA-1', 'CABINATE')
dot.node('YPN-AN-1-1', 'AN1')
dot.node('YPN-AN-2-1', 'AN2')
dot.node('YPN-AN-3-1', 'AN3')
dot.node('YPN-AN-4-1', 'AN4')
dot.node('YPN-PN-102', 'PN')
dot.node('YPN-IJ-102', 'IJ')

dot.edge('YPN-CA-1', 'YPN-AN-1-1', label='YPN-SN-1-1')
dot.edge('YPN-AN-1-1', 'YPN-AN-2-1', label='YPN-SN-1-2')
dot.edge('YPN-AN-2-1', 'YPN-AN-3-1', label='YPN-SN-1-3')
dot.edge('YPN-AN-3-1', 'YPN-AN-4-1', label='YPN-SN-1-4')
dot.edge('YPN-AN-4-1', 'YPN-PN-102', label='Fiber')
dot.edge('YPN-PN-102', 'YPN-IJ-102', label='Fiber')
dot.render(directory=r'D:\SLD-diagram\doctest-output', view=True)
```